# \@for does not compose with \StrSubstitute

Tags: loops, xstring, comma-separated-list

I want to split a space-delimited string into parts and generate code for each part. Apparently TeX works with comma-delimited strings natively so I tried writing an adaptation

```
\usepackage{xstring}    
\makeatletter
\@for\next:=foo,bar,baz\do{X \next Y} \\
\StrSubstitute{foo bar baz}{ }{,} \\
\@for\next:=\StrSubstitute{foo bar baz}{ }{,}\do{X \next Y}
\makeatother
```

[image]

The first line of output for a comma-delimited string is correct. The second line of output showing a space-delimited-string being transformed into the corresponding comma-delimited string is correct.

However, in the third line, the second `\@for`, the string isn't being split.

Why not and how do I fix this?

Comment: Most likely `StrSubstitute` is not expandable

Comment: tex doesn't have built in support for comma  or space delimited strings (or really any notion of string at all) it will be doing as much work looping through your input changing spaces to commas  so that you can iterate over commas as it would have done had you simply looped through spaces to start with, and then you still have to loop through the comma list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\StrSubstitute` has multiple optional arguments and can't be expandable, so it is not possible to use the output from `\StrSubstitute` and feed it again into TeX's input stream.

It is possible to store the result of `\StrSubstitute` to a temporary macro and use this macro as input to `\@for\next`....

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}   

\begin{document} 
\makeatletter
\@for\next:=foo,bar,baz\do{X \next Y} \\
\StrSubstitute{foo bar baz}{ }{,} \\
\StrSubstitute{foo bar baz}{ }{,}[\@stuff]
\@for\next:=\@stuff\do{X \next Y}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Other possibility: Use `expl3` and a `\tl_replace....` macro

Comment: Much better: `\seq_set_split:Nnn` and then `\seq_map_inline:Nn` or `\seq_map_function:NN`

Comment: @egreg: I know, but I don't have time right now.

Answer (score 2):

If the requirement is to loop through a space separated list there is no need to replace spaces by commas and loop through a comma separated list. Implementing that replace already probably requires the ability to iterate over the spaces.

For example this iterates over the space separated words putting each in an fbox.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\zz#1{\zzz#1 \! }

\def\zzz#1 {\ifx\!#1\else\fbox{#1} \expandafter\zzz\fi}
\begin{document}

\zz{foo bar baz}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `listofitems` package can parse, based on a specified multiplicity of characters, here given as a space  and comma `,`.  Thus, one definition of `\setsepchar` solves all cases, without the use of `xstring`.  EDITED to embody solution in the macro `\processlist`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\setsepchar{ ||,}%
\newcommand\processlist[1]{%
  \readlist\mylist{#1}%
  \foreachitem\next\in\mylist{X \next Y}%
}
\begin{document}
\processlist{foo,bar,baz}

\processlist{foo bar baz}
\end{document}
```

[image]